# Link from UIwebview to UItableviewcell

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview, hyperlink

I have UIwebview in custom UItableviewcell. I want when i touch on a link in UIwebview, it will link to tableviewcell with link's name. I'm making a dictionary  app.
Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

For UIWebView: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

UITableviewcell is explained here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html